# Inner Join: Sum of values in different tables with inner join and 0 when no hit on both sides

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I use MS-SQL and have the following two tables, where I want to extract the values to create the third table within one SQL query.

The answer from here helped me, but it's not enough.

[sql sum data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591390/sql-sum-data-from-multiple-tables)

Also it is important for me, that when there is no deregistration or no registration but a deregistration (fautly) I have to get the value 0 for that, so I need to have also results without a hit in both tables, but only in one.

Is it possible to get this result within one SQL query?

**REG**

```
[ATE]   [Article]  [Description] [Registered]     
------------------------------------------
[1111]  [MS1234]      [SCREW]     [500]  
[2222]  [MS1234]      [SCREW]     [600]  
[2222]  [AB9999]       [BOLT]     [100]  
[3333]  [XYZ123]      [PAINT]     [900]  
[4444]  [LMU232]       [TOOL]     [120]
```

**DEREG**

```
[ATE]   [Article]  [Description] [Deregistered]     
------------------------------------------
[1111]  [MS1234]      [SCREW]     [260]  
[3333]  [XYZ123]      [PAINT]     [900]  
[4444]  [LMU232]       [TOOL]      [20]  
[9999]  [TUM933]       [SHIM]    [5000]
```

**RES**

```
[ATE]   [Article]  [Description] [Registered] [Deregistered]    [Rest]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1111]  [MS1234]      [SCREW]        [500]        [260]         [240]
[2222]  [MS1234]      [SCREW]        [600]          [0]         [600]
[2222]  [AB9999]       [BOLT]        [100]          [0]         [100]
[3333]  [XYZ123]      [PAINT]        [900]        [900]           [0]
[4444]  [LMU232]       [TOOL]        [120]         [20]         [100]
[9999]  [TUM933]       [SHIM]          [0]       [5000]       [-5000]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far. And why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can `full outer join` to get records coming from both tables:

```
select 
    coalesce(r.ate, d.ate) ate, 
    coalesce(r.article, d.article) article, 
    coalesce(r.description, d.description) description, 
    coalesce(r.registered, 0) registered,
    coalesce(d.deregistered, 0) deregistered,
    coalesce(r.registered, 0) - coalesce(d.deregistered, 0) rest
from reg r
full outer join dereg d on d.ate = r.ate and d.article = r.article
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75bc0f34d17a50a1354bf8174b2b6697)**:

```
 ate | article | description | registered | deregistered |  rest
---: | :------ | :---------- | ---------: | -----------: | ----:
1111 | MS1234  | SCREW       |        500 |          260 |   240
2222 | MS1234  | SCREW       |        600 |            0 |   600
2222 | AB9999  | BOLT        |        100 |            0 |   100
3333 | XYZ123  | PAINT       |        900 |          900 |     0
4444 | LMU232  | TOOL        |        120 |           20 |   100
9999 | TUM933  | SHIM        |          0 |         5000 | -5000
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I get the message "sql missing operator in query expression 'coalesce(r.ate, d.ate) ate'

Comment: @ManfredSinger: I just fixed a typo (missing comma), is it working now?

Comment: I saw this already and tried it with the comma, but it doesnt work.

Comment: @ManfredSinger: this seems to work fine. I added a db fiddle to my answer for your reference. Are you using ms-access (which the error message seems to indicate), or sql-server (which you tagged your question with)? `full join` is not supported in ms-access.

Comment: In this case I use ODBC for Excel. Inner join works, but not full outer join